# Remove Single Quote from Middle of the String but not from start and end

Tags: java

I have a string like

```
 String abc = "'Joe's Dinner'";
```

Now i need to remove the quote from the middle so that the result can be like

```
abc = "'Joes Dinner'"
```

**Edited:**
I realized the problem occurs in somewhere else. actually I splitting a 5 GB XML file. I am using StAX to do that. And here is my code.

```
public String split(String fileName){
  XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
  XMLEventReader xer = xif.createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(new File(fileName)));

  String fileContent = "";

  while(xer.hasNext()) {
    XMLEvent e = xer.nextEvent();
    fileContent = fileContent + e.toString();
  }
  return fileContent;
}
```

Now, in my source XML the line comes as

```
<location state="Côte d'Azur" xsi:nil="true" city="Marseille" country="FRANCE"></location>
```

but in output the double quote in attribute values are changed to single quote resulting an error while parsing. Is there any way to keep that double quote as it is.

Comment: Have you tried searching on SO?. Can you show us some code?

Comment: Is it just `"'Joe's Dinner'"` or it's more like `"...text text 'Joe's Dinner' text text..."` ?

Comment: I am actually trying regex and what i have found is actually picking the starting single quote also. No luck yet.

Comment: <location state='Côte d'Azur' xsi:nil='true' city='Marseille' country='FRANCE'></location>. now i need to remove the single quote from Côte d'Azur but the starting and end quote should remain.

Comment: @BitanBiswas are all the files in xml format or that's just one of multiple possible cases?

Comment: mainly in XML and that is where I am struggling.

Comment: Are you generating the xml yourself or do you get it from somebody?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question, then you need something like that, i make three olutions to solve your problem,

```
public class Cote {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //First Solution
        String abc = "'Joe's Dinner'";

        //Second Solution
        String abc3 = "'" + abc.replace("'", "") + "'";
        System.out.println(abc3);

        String abc2 = "'";
        for (int i = 1; i < abc.length() - 1; i++) {
            String c = abc.charAt(i) + "";
            if (!c.equals("'")) {
                abc2 += c;
            }
        }
        abc2 += "'";
        System.out.println(abc2);

        //Third Solution
        abc = "<location state='Côte d'Azur' xsi:nil='true' city='Marseille' country='FRANCE'></location>";
        abc2 = "";
        int count = abc.length() - abc.replace("'", "").length();

        int count2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < abc.length(); i++) {
            String c = abc.charAt(i) + "";
            if (c.equals("'")) {
                count2++;
                if (count2 == 1 || count2 == count) {
                    abc2 += c;
                }
            } else {
                abc2 += c;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(abc2);
    }
}
```

Good luck

Comment: Offtopic but thansk!

Comment: what did you mean @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nice feature of regexps called positive look-ahead/look-behind, which means you can matching things which will not be considered part of the actual match. In this case you want to ignore the starting and ending characters of the string, so the replacement would be:

```
input.replaceAll("(?<=.)'(?=.)", "");
```

Where the first parenthesized part reads "proceeded by any character" and the second part means "followed by any character".

If you would like to keep the quote without corrupting your xml you might want to escape it instead, in which case you could use

```
input.replaceAll("(?<=.)'(?=.)", "&apos;");
```

Good lock!

Comment: why not use start and end of the line check `(?<!^)'(?!$)`